# удалить дубликаты строк из файла, сохранив порядок

Tags: сортировка, shell, gnu

имеется файл со строками, среди которых попадаются дубли.

как средствами утилит *gnu/coreutils* из операционной системы *gnu* (совместимость со стандартом *posix* не требуется) удалить дубли, не нарушив порядок строк?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

например, можно воспользоваться такой конструкцией:

```
$ nl исходный-файл | sort -k 2 -u | sort -n | cut -f 2- > отсортированный-файл
```

---

пояснения:

- `nl` — выдаст в *stdout* строки из *stdin* (или прочитанные из файлов, переданных аргументами), добавив в начале строк последовательные нумера; номер и остальное содержимое по умолчанию будет разделять символ табуляции
- `sort -k 2 -u` — отсортирует переданный список по второму и последующим (`-k 2`) полям (поля по умолчанию разделяет символ табуляции) и удалит дубликаты (`-u`) в том же самом втором поле (не обращая внимания на первое); просто «удалять дубликаты» без сортировки программа *sort* «не умеет»
- `sort -n` — отсортирует список в числовой (`-n`) последовательности; так как в начале строк находятся номера, то получится список строк, отсортированных в том же порядке, что и «в самом начале» (только уже с пропусками)
- `cut -f 2-` — оставит только поля со второго «и дальше» (`-f 2-`); поля по умолчанию, как обычно, отделяются символом табуляции

---

доп. чтение:

```
$ info coreutils
```

если программа *info* не установлена, можно почитать [документацию онлайн](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/) или отдельные man-страницы (но там, обычно, меньше информации):

```
$ man nl
$ man sort
$ man cut
```

Answer (score 3):

Вариант с `awk`

```
$ awk '!a[$0]++' исходный-файл
```

Здесь каждая строка файла становится ключом для ассоциативного массива `a`. Если строка встретилась первый раз, то массив ещё не содержит такой элемент, и отрицание `!` дает для такой строки `true`, т.е. она проходит на выход. Если же  строка встречается повторно, то мы уже имеем ненулевой элемент с ключом-строкой в массиве (обратите внимание на постинкремент), соответственно выражение вычислиться как `false` и строка будет проигнорирована.

Comment: хороший вариант. отсутствием программы *awk* в *gnu/coreutils*, думаю, можно пренебречь.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin действительно нету, почему то казалось что awk из coreutils.

Comment: в операционной системе *gnu* есть, конечно, своя реализация *awk*, но это отдельный пакет, с *coreutils* непосредственно не связанный.