# в файле удалить строки, у которых начало строки повторяется

Tags: сортировка, shell, sed

есть файл file.txt содержащий строки:

```
536|разный текст|еще какойто текст|какие то цифры
6352|разный текст|еще какойто текст|какие то цифры
723|разный текст|еще какойто текст|какие то цифры
37|разный текст|еще какойто текст|какие то цифры
....и тд.
```

нужно удалить те строки, у которых цифра в самом начале строки (идет перед символом "|") уже встречается в другой строке в этом же месте (то есть в самом начале перед первым символом "|").

то есть, удалить дубли, но дубль, если совпадает не вся строка, а только первый "столбец", но удаляться должна вся строка,

удаляться должны не оба варианта, какой-то один должен остаться.

таких "дублей" одной строки в файле может быть больше двух.

Comment: У вас большинство вопросов касаются **regex**, так задача regex найти последовательность согласно шаблона, а не дубликаты. Максимум что можно сделать тут через regex, это отделить текст с начала строки до значка `|`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

с помощью программы *sed* это сделать довольно проблематично.

с помощью программы *sort* — элементарно:

```
$ sort -t '|' -k 1,1 -u файл > результат
```

- `-t символ` — разделитель полей
- `-k 1,1` — сортировать по первому полю
- `-u` — удалить дубликаты

---

подробности см. в `man sort`

---

если важно сохранить порядок строк, то [конструкция несколько длиннее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/537605/178576):

```
$ nl -s '|' файл | sort -t '|' -k 2,2 -u | sort -n | cut -f 2- -d '|' > результат
```