# Как вырезать случайные строки из файла и сохранить в другой?

Tags: bash

Подскажите как извлечь 100 000 случайных строк из файла с сохранением в новый файл и удалением оных в исходном.

Есть "файлA" с 300 000 строк. Как вырезать 100 000 случайных строк (вырезать, то есть скопировать удалив их в "файлеА") и сохранить их в "файлБ".

Чтобы в результате в "файлеА" осталось 200 000 строк, а в новом "файлеБ" - 100 000

Comment: «вырезать« — это «удалить» или «извлечь»?

Comment: извлечь удалив в исходном файле

Comment: т.е. нужно сохранить **отдельно** указанное количество строк **и** получить новый файл, уже не содержащий эти строки? вы бы лучше переформулировали вопрос, приведя пример: что у вас есть и что хотите получить в результате.

Comment: Да все верно, либо удалить в оригинальном файле

Comment: «либо»??? всё-таки переформулируйте текст вопроса, пожалуйста, как я подсказал в предыдущем комментарии.

Comment: Поправил, как надо

Comment: добавил вторую версию ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### ответ на новую версию вопроса:

1. перемешиваем строки файла и сохраняем в файл `перемешанные`:

   ```
   $ shuf файл > перемешанные
   ```
2. берём из файла `перемешанные` указанное `число` строк (от начала файла) и сохраняем в файл `вырезанные`:

   ```
   $ head -n число перемешанные > вырезанные
   ```
3. берём из файла `перемешанные` строки, начиная с `число+1` и сохраняем в исходный `файл`:

   ```
   $ tail -n +$((число+1)) перемешанные > файл
   ```
4. удаляем уже не нужный файл `перемешанные`:

   ```
   $ rm перемешанные
   ```

---

если требуется сохранить тот же порядок строк, что и в исходном файле, то надо добавить нумерацию (*nl*), сортировку (*sort*) и удаление номеров (*cut*). здесь без комментариев, только команды (подробности смотрите ниже, в ответе на предыдущую версию вопроса):

```
$ nl файл | shuf > перемешанные
$ head -n число перемешанные | sort -n | cut -f 2- > вырезанные
$ tail -n +$((число+1)) перемешанные | sort -n | cut -f 2- > файл
$ rm перемешанные
```

---

приведённые последовательности команд можно записать в одну строчку, если воспользоваться программой *pee* из пакета [*moreutils*](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=moreutils&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all).

- вариант, если порядок строк не важен:

  ```
  $ shuf файл | pee "head -n число > вырезанные" "tail -n +$((число+1)) > файл"
  ```
- вариант, если порядок строк важен:

  ```
  $ nl файл | shuf | pee "head -n число | sort -n | cut -f 2- > вырезанные" "tail -n +$((число+1)) | sort -n | cut -f 2- > файл"
  ```

### ответ на предыдущую версию вопроса:

команда

```
$ shuf файл
```

выдаст в *stdout* строки из `файл`а в случайном порядке. а команда

```
$ shuf -n число файл
```

ограничит этот вывод указанным `число`м строк.

если же требуется получить число строк, составляющее разность между количеством строк файла и указанным `число`м, то в предыдущую команду вместо `число` надо подставить конструкцию, вычисляющую эту разность — `$(($(cat файл | wc -l) - число))`:

```
$ shuf -n $(($(cat файл | wc -l) - число)) файл
```

---

всё полученное можно сохранить в новый файл (в исходный, увы, нельзя), добавив в конце перенаправление — `> новый.файл`:

```
$ shuf -n $(($(cat файл | wc -l) - число)) файл > новый.файл
```

---

в полученном новом файле строки будут следовать в случайном порядке. если требуется [сохранить тот же порядок строк](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/537605/178576), что и в исходном файле, то можно предварительно строки пронумеровать (например, с помощью программы *nl*), а затем, в конце, отсортировать (*sort*) и эти номера удалить (например, с помощью программы *cut*):

```
$ nl файл | shuf -n $(($(cat файл | wc -l) - число)) | sort -n | cut -f 2- > новый.файл
```

Comment: поскольку требуется сохранить все строки только в разных файлах, наверно надо shuf сделать полностью, потом разрезать его на 2 части и восстановить порядок

Comment: @sercxjo, ответ писался до того, как автор вопроса «поставил его с ног на голову». сейчас перепишу под текущую редакцию вопроса.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Вы этот ответ не удаляйте, это тоже пригодится