# Удаление дубликатов из списка без сортировки

Tags: python, linux, список

Как удалить дубликаты без сортировки с сохранением порядка исходного списка в текстовом документе? Средствами linux или python.
Или как вариант: имеется список1 (не сортированный), список2 (не сортированный). Как добавить список2 в конец списка1, но при этом исключить дубликаты из списка2, которые уже есть в списке1 и при этом порядок слов должен остаться прежним. Спасибо

Comment: «средствами» программы *linux* это сделать невозможно: она предназначена совсем для других задач (служить ядром в ряде операционных систем). а вот средствами некоторых других программ — [запросто](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/537604/178576)

Comment: спасибо, я почему-то не нашел этот вопрос. Больше понравилось `$ awk '!a[$0]++' исходный-файл`

Comment: да, решение интересное, но очень затратное в плане использования оперативной памяти при увеличении входного файла (в сравнении с предложенным мною решением, где размер файла, насколько я понимаю, вообще никак не влияет на размер используемой памяти).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin вообще говоря, оно должно быть и быстрее (приближается к O(N)) и менее затратно по памяти (O(n) против O(N), где N — кол-во строк в файле, а n — кол-во уникальных строк), чем решение с sort'ом...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, возможно. потестировать бы. да лень.

Comment: С потерей связей легко: `newlist = list(set(mylist))`. Возможно есть модификация библиотечного `set`, сохраняющего порядок.

Comment: for i in list2:
    if not i in list1:
        list1.append(i)